# Access 2010 SQL: Multiple Condition Where Clause not filtering properly

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010, where-clause

I am attempting to write an SQL query for MS Access 2010 to select any combination of 6 fields. I have written the 63 possible combinations into my query, each bracketed and separated by an OR. Internally, each is joined by AND. Furthermore, each field is set to request parameters from the user.

The problem I am encountering is that if I enter parameters for (example) fields A, B, and C, I am only returned filtered values for A and B, while the query displays items that do not meet the parameter criteria.

Code Example:

```
`SELECT Main.DISPATCHER, Main.DateCall, Main.Status, Main.[Pick Up 20], Main.[Drop Off 20], Main.Shift, Main.Day, Main.Time, Main.[Call Type], Main.[ETA Given], Main.ZONE, Main.Priority, Main.Comments, Main.DODept, Main.ID, Main.PU, Main.DO, Main.[Pick Up], Main.Caller, Main.DropOff
FROM Main
WHERE (Main.DISPATCHER=[Which Dispatcher?Ex Justin]
       AND Main.DateCall BETWEEN [Enter Start Date:] AND [Enter Ending Date:]
       AND Main.Status=[Status: ACCEPTED or DECLINED?]
       AND Main.[Pick Up 20]=[What Pick Up?Use Facility List]
       AND Main.[Drop Off 20]=[What Drop Off?-Use Facility List]
       AND Main.Shift=[What shift?AM/PM])
  OR (Main.DISPATCHER=[Which Dispatcher?Ex Justin]
      AND Main.DateCall BETWEEN [Enter Start Date:] AND [Enter Ending Date:]
      AND Main.Status=[Status: ACCEPTED or DECLINED?]
      AND Main.[Pick Up 20]=[What Pick Up?Use Facility List]
      AND Main.[Drop Off 20]=[What Drop Off?-Use Facility List])
  OR (Main.DISPATCHER=[Which Dispatcher?Ex Justin]
      AND Main.DateCall BETWEEN [Enter Start Date:] AND [Enter Ending Date:]
      AND Main.Status=[Status: ACCEPTED or DECLINED?]
      AND Main.[Pick Up 20]=[What Pick Up?Use Facility List])
  OR (Main.DISPATCHER=[Which Dispatcher?Ex Justin]
      AND Main.DateCall BETWEEN [Enter Start Date:] AND [Enter Ending Date:]
      AND Main.Status=[Status: ACCEPTED or DECLINED?])
  OR (Main.DISPATCHER=[Which Dispatcher?Ex Justin]
      AND Main.DateCall BETWEEN [Enter Start Date:] AND [Enter Ending Date:])
  OR (Main.DISPATCHER=[Which Dispatcher?Ex Justin]
      AND Main.[Pick Up 20]=[What Pick Up?Use Facility List])
  OR (Main.DISPATCHER=[Which Dispatcher?Ex Justin]
      AND Main.[Pick Up 20]=[What Pick Up?Use Facility List])
  OR (Main.DISPATCHER=[Which Dispatcher?Ex Justin]
      AND Main.[Drop Off 20]=[What Drop Off?-Use Facility List])
  OR (Main.DISPATCHER=[Which Dispatcher?Ex Justin]
      AND Main.Shift=[What shift?AM/PM])
  OR (Main.DateCall BETWEEN [Enter Start Date:] AND [Enter Ending Date:]
      AND Main.Status=[Status: ACCEPTED or DECLINED?])
  OR (Main.DateCall BETWEEN [Enter Start Date:] AND [Enter Ending Date:]
      AND Main.[Pick Up 20]=[What Pick Up?Use Facility List])
  OR (Main.DateCall BETWEEN [Enter Start Date:] AND [Enter Ending Date:]
      AND Main.[Drop Off 20]=[What Drop Off?-Use Facility List])
  OR (Main.DateCall BETWEEN [Enter Start Date:] AND [Enter Ending Date:]
      AND Main.Shift=[What shift?AM/PM])
  OR (Main.Status=[Status: ACCEPTED or DECLINED?]
      AND Main.[Pick Up 20]=[What Pick Up?Use Facility List])
  OR (Main.Status=[Status: ACCEPTED or DECLINED?]
      AND Main.[Drop Off 20]=[What Drop Off?-Use Facility List])
  OR (Main.Status=[Status: ACCEPTED or DECLINED?]
      AND Main.Shift=[What shift?AM/PM])
  OR (Main.[Pick Up 20]=[What Pick Up?Use Facility List]
      AND Main.[Drop Off 20]=[What Drop Off?-Use Facility List])
  OR (Main.[Pick Up 20]=[What Pick Up?Use Facility List]
      AND Main.Shift=[What shift?AM/PM]
      AND Main.DISPATCHER=[Which Dispatcher?Ex Justin])
  OR (Main.DISPATCHER=[Which Dispatcher?Ex Justin]
      AND Main.DateCall BETWEEN [Enter Start Date:] AND [Enter Ending Date:]
      AND Main.Status=[Status: ACCEPTED or DECLINED?]
      AND Main.[Pick Up 20]=[What Pick Up?Use Facility List]
      AND Main.Shift=[What shift?AM/PM])
  OR (Main.DISPATCHER=[Which Dispatcher?Ex Justin]
      AND Main.DateCall BETWEEN [Enter Start Date:] AND [Enter Ending Date:]
      AND Main.Status=[Status: ACCEPTED or DECLINED?]
      AND Main.[Drop Off 20]=[What Drop Off?-Use Facility List])
  OR (Main.DISPATCHER=[Which Dispatcher?Ex Justin]
      AND Main.DateCall BETWEEN [Enter Start Date:] AND [Enter Ending Date:]
      AND Main.Status=[Status: ACCEPTED or DECLINED?]
      AND Main.[Drop Off 20]=[What Drop Off?-Use Facility List]
      AND Main.Shift=[What shift?AM/PM])
  OR Main.DISPATCHER=[Which Dispatcher?Ex Justin]
  AND Main.DateCall BETWEEN [Enter Start Date:] AND [Enter Ending Date:]
  AND Main.Status=[Status: ACCEPTED or DECLINED?]
  AND Main.Shift=[What shift?AM/PM]
  OR (Main.DISPATCHER=[Which Dispatcher?Ex Justin]
      AND Main.DateCall BETWEEN [Enter Start Date:] AND [Enter Ending Date:]
      AND Main.[Pick Up 20]=[What Pick Up?Use Facility List])
  OR (Main.DISPATCHER=[Which Dispatcher?Ex Justin]
      AND Main.DateCall BETWEEN [Enter Start Date:] AND [Enter Ending Date:]
      AND Main.[Pick Up 20]=[What Pick Up?Use Facility List]
      AND Main.[Drop Off 20]=[What Drop Off?-Use Facility List])
  OR (Main.DISPATCHER=[Which Dispatcher?Ex Justin]
      AND Main.DateCall BETWEEN [Enter Start Date:] AND [Enter Ending Date:]
      AND Main.[Pick Up 20]=[What Pick Up?Use Facility List]
      AND Main.[Drop Off 20]=[What Drop Off?-Use Facility List]
      AND Main.Shift=[What shift?AM/PM])
  OR (Main.DISPATCHER=[Which Dispatcher?Ex Justin]
      AND Main.DateCall BETWEEN [Enter Start Date:] AND [Enter Ending Date:]
      AND Main.[Pick Up 20]=[What Pick Up?Use Facility List]
      AND Main.Shift=[What shift?AM/PM])
  OR (Main.DISPATCHER=[Which Dispatcher?Ex Justin]
      AND Main.DateCall BETWEEN [Enter Start Date:] AND [Enter Ending Date:]
      AND Main.[Drop Off 20]=[What Drop Off?-Use Facility List])
  OR (Main.DISPATCHER=[Which Dispatcher?Ex Justin]
      AND Main.DateCall BETWEEN [Enter Start Date:] AND [Enter Ending Date:]
      AND Main.[Drop Off 20]=[What Drop Off?-Use Facility List]
      AND Main.Shift=[What shift?AM/PM])
  OR (Main.DISPATCHER=[Which Dispatcher?Ex Justin]
      AND Main.DateCall BETWEEN [Enter Start Date:] AND [Enter Ending Date:]
      AND Main.Shift=[What shift?AM/PM])
  OR (Main.DISPATCHER=[Which Dispatcher?Ex Justin]
      AND Main.Status=[Status: ACCEPTED or DECLINED?]
      AND Main.[Pick Up 20]=[What Pick Up?Use Facility List])
  OR (Main.DISPATCHER=[Which Dispatcher?Ex Justin]
      AND Main.Status=[Status: ACCEPTED or DECLINED?]
      AND Main.[Pick Up 20]=[What Pick Up?Use Facility List]
      AND Main.[Drop Off 20]=[What Drop Off?-Use Facility List])
  OR (Main.DISPATCHER=[Which Dispatcher?Ex Justin]
      AND Main.Status=[Status: ACCEPTED or DECLINED?]
      AND Main.[Pick Up 20]=[What Pick Up?Use Facility List]
      AND Main.[Drop Off 20]=[What Drop Off?-Use Facility List]
      AND Main.Shift=[What shift?AM/PM])
  OR (Main.DISPATCHER=[Which Dispatcher?Ex Justin]
      AND Main.Status=[Status: ACCEPTED or DECLINED?]
      AND Main.[Pick Up 20]=[What Pick Up?Use Facility List]
      AND Main.Shift=[What shift?AM/PM])
  OR (Main.DISPATCHER=[Which Dispatcher?Ex Justin]
      AND Main.Status=[Status: ACCEPTED or DECLINED?]
      AND Main.[Drop Off 20]=[What Drop Off?-Use Facility List])
  OR (Main.DISPATCHER=[Which Dispatcher?Ex Justin]
      AND Main.Status=[Status: ACCEPTED or DECLINED?]
      AND Main.[Drop Off 20]=[What Drop Off?-Use Facility List]
      AND Main.Shift=[What shift?AM/PM])
  OR (Main.DISPATCHER=[Which Dispatcher?Ex Justin]
      AND Main.Status=[Status: ACCEPTED or DECLINED?]
      AND Main.Shift=[What shift?AM/PM])
  OR (Main.DISPATCHER=[Which Dispatcher?Ex Justin]
      AND Main.[Pick Up 20]=[What Pick Up?Use Facility List]
      AND Main.[Drop Off 20]=[What Drop Off?-Use Facility List])
  OR (Main.DISPATCHER=[Which Dispatcher?Ex Justin]
      AND Main.[Pick Up 20]=[What Pick Up?Use Facility List]
      AND Main.[Drop Off 20]=[What Drop Off?-Use Facility List]
      AND Main.Shift=[What shift?AM/PM])
  OR (Main.DISPATCHER=[Which Dispatcher?Ex jUSTIN]
      AND Main.[Pick Up 20]=[What Pick Up?Use Facility List]
      AND Main.Shift=[What shift?AM/PM])
  OR (Main.DISPATCHER=[Which Dispatcher?Ex Justin]
      AND Main.[Drop Off 20]=[What Drop Off?-Use Facility List]
      AND Main.Shift=[What shift?AM/PM])
  OR (Main.DateCall BETWEEN [Enter Start Date:] AND [Enter Ending Date:])
  OR (Main.DateCall BETWEEN [Enter Start Date:] AND [Enter Ending Date:]
      AND Main.Status=[Status: ACCEPTED or DECLINED?]
      AND Main.[Pick Up 20]=[What Pick Up?Use Facility List])
  OR (Main.DateCall BETWEEN [Enter Start Date:] AND [Enter Ending Date:]
      AND Main.Status=[Status: ACCEPTED or DECLINED?]
      AND Main.[Pick Up 20]=[What Pick Up?Use Facility List]
      AND Main.[Drop Off 20]=[What Drop Off?-Use Facility List])
  OR (Main.DateCall BETWEEN [Enter Start Date:] AND [Enter Ending Date:]
      AND Main.Status=[Status: ACCEPTED or DECLINED?]
      AND Main.[Pick Up 20]=[What Pick Up?Use Facility List]
      AND Main.[Drop Off 20]=[What Drop Off?-Use Facility List]
      AND Main.Shift=[What shift?AM/PM])
  OR (Main.DateCall BETWEEN [Enter Start Date:] AND [Enter Ending Date:]
      AND Main.Status=[Status: ACCEPTED or DECLINED?]
      AND Main.[Pick Up 20]=[What Pick Up?Use Facility List]
      AND Main.Shift=[What shift?AM/PM])
  OR (Main.DateCall BETWEEN [Enter Start Date:] AND [Enter Ending Date:]
      AND Main.Status=[Status: ACCEPTED or DECLINED?]
      AND Main.[Drop Off 20]=[What Drop Off?-Use Facility List])
  OR (Main.DateCall BETWEEN [Enter Start Date:] AND [Enter Ending Date:]
      AND Main.Status=[Status: ACCEPTED or DECLINED?]
      AND Main.[Drop Off 20]=[What Drop Off?-Use Facility List]
      AND Main.Shift=[What shift?AM/PM])
  OR (Main.DateCall BETWEEN [Enter Start Date:] AND [Enter Ending Date:]
      AND Main.Status=[Status: ACCEPTED or DECLINED?]
      AND Main.Shift=[What shift?AM/PM])
  OR (Main.DateCall BETWEEN [Enter Start Date:] AND [Enter Ending Date:]
      AND Main.[Pick Up 20]=[What Pick Up?Use Facility List]
      AND Main.[Drop Off 20]=[What Drop Off?-Use Facility List])
  OR (Main.DateCall BETWEEN [Enter Start Date:] AND [Enter Ending Date:]
      AND Main.[Pick Up 20]=[What Pick Up?Use Facility List]
      AND Main.[Drop Off 20]=[What Drop Off?-Use Facility List]
      AND Main.Shift=[What shift?AM/PM])
  OR (Main.DateCall BETWEEN [Enter Start Date:] AND [Enter Ending Date:]
      AND Main.[Pick Up 20]=[What Pick Up?Use Facility List]
      AND Main.Shift=[What shift?AM/PM])
  OR (Main.DateCall BETWEEN [Enter Start Date:] AND [Enter Ending Date:]
      AND Main.[Drop Off 20]=[What Drop Off?-Use Facility List]
      AND Main.Shift=[What shift?AM/PM])
  OR (Main.Status=[Status: ACCEPTED or DECLINED?])
  OR (Main.Status=[Status: ACCEPTED or DECLINED?]
      AND Main.[Pick Up 20]=[What Pick Up?Use Facility List]
      AND Main.[Drop Off 20]=[What Drop Off?-Use Facility List])
  OR (Main.Status=[Status: ACCEPTED or DECLINED?]
      AND Main.[Pick Up 20]=[What Pick Up?Use Facility List]
      AND Main.[Drop Off 20]=[What Drop Off?-Use Facility List]
      AND Main.Shift=[What shift?AM/PM])
  OR (Main.Status=[Status: ACCEPTED or DECLINED?]
      AND Main.[Pick Up 20]=[What Pick Up?Use Facility List]
      AND Main.Shift=[What shift?AM/PM])
  OR (Main.Status=[Status: ACCEPTED or DECLINED?]
      AND Main.[Drop Off 20]=[What Drop Off?-Use Facility List]
      AND Main.Shift=[What shift?AM/PM])
  OR (Main.[Pick Up 20]=[What Pick Up?Use Facility List])
  OR (Main.[Pick Up 20]=[What Pick Up?Use Facility List]
      AND Main.[Drop Off 20]=[What Drop Off?-Use Facility List]
      AND Main.Shift=[What shift?AM/PM])
  OR (Main.[Drop Off 20]=[What Drop Off?-Use Facility List]
      AND Main.Shift=[What shift?AM/PM])
  OR (Main.Shift=[What shift?AM/PM]);`
```

Any help/logic would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: jeezus, are all of those `AND`s and `OR`s needed?

Comment: Its the only way I could think/find to potentially produce the desired results

Comment: Are any of your database columns NULL? Comparing against NULL does not work like normal boolean logic.

Comment: No entire column is null, but a few cells are. Would this adversely affect the performance?

Comment: I don't think all the `ORs`  are actually needed, e,g, your logic includes `OR (Main.Status=[Status: ACCEPTED or DECLINED?])` and then some other `OR` with the same condition plus some additional ones, those are redundant.

Comment: Precisely, each bracketed group is some combination of the possible fields. How would one write this without dictating the possible combinations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, that's not a very efficient way to search.  I mean, this:

```
OR (Main.Status=[Status: ACCEPTED or DECLINED?])
OR (Main.Status=[Status: ACCEPTED or DECLINED?]
  AND Main.[Pick Up 20]=[What Pick Up?Use Facility List]
  AND Main.[Drop Off 20]=[What Drop Off?-Use Facility List])
```

Is logically equivalent to just this:

```
OR (Main.Status=[Status: ACCEPTED or DECLINED?])
```

Then in the middle you have a bunch of AND statements.

```
[...]
OR Main.DISPATCHER=[Which Dispatcher?Ex Justin]
AND Main.DateCall BETWEEN [Enter Start Date:] AND [Enter Ending Date:]
AND Main.Status=[Status: ACCEPTED or DECLINED?]
AND Main.Shift=[What shift?AM/PM]
OR [...]
```

And that's going to basically override everything else you've got.  *All* those conditions have to be satisfied.

Let's assume that when you don't submit a field that the value of the prompt is NULL.  Let's also assume you have to submit both dates for the call date range.  To do a complete search, you can do this:

```
WHERE (Main.DISPATCHER=[Which Dispatcher?Ex Justin] OR [Which Dispatcher?Ex Justin] IS NULL)
    AND (Main.DateCall BETWEEN [Enter Start Date:] AND [Enter Ending Date:] OR [Enter Start Date:] IS NULL OR [Enter Ending Date:] IS NULL)
    AND (Main.Status=[Status: ACCEPTED or DECLINED?] OR [Status: ACCEPTED or DECLINED?] IS NULL)
    AND (Main.[Pick Up 20]=[What Pick Up?Use Facility List] OR [What Pick Up?Use Facility List] IS NULL)
    AND (Main.[Drop Off 20]=[What Drop Off?-Use Facility List] OR [What Drop Off?-Use Facility List] IS NULL)
    AND (Main.Shift=[What shift?AM/PM] OR [What shift?AM/PM] IS NULL)
```

Comment: I see the logic behind your suggestion but it is now returning all results. I have tried entering multiple parameter combinations, all of which included start and end dates.

Comment: @atomedic I'm afraid I don't know, then, because unless you're missing parentheses somewhere that should work.  I'd start by eliminating all but one or two of the most simple conditions (i.e., just pick up 20 and drop off 20), and get it to work for that.  That should tell you how the condition needs to be written.

Comment: Removed a parenthesis from the last line and nested the entire where clause in another set of parantheses and it started to work! Thank you very much Bacon Bits.

Comment: @atomedic Ah, yeah, it looks like I left a parenthesis in there, too.  I thought I'd gotten them all.  Sorry about that!